# font face file url in request uri

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, request-uri

I have some issue with font_face

In css:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Optima';
    src: url('fonts/OPTIMA_0.woff') format('woff');           
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}   
html{  
    font-family: 'Optima';
}
```

I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for MVC routing, like:

site.com/main - call common page 'main'

site.com/contacts - call common page 'contacts'

site.com/services - call catalog page 'services'

site.com/services/serviceA - call concrete catalog page 'serviceA'

site.com/services/serviceB - call concrete catalog page 'serviceB'

....

But when I clear browser cache on page reload, I got font path in request uri, like:
site.com/application/css/fonts/OPTIMA_0.woff, not site.com/services/serviceA

In browser address bar I got correct uri

And the google fonts works fine, but i need this one..

Looks like font not load properly on page reload, but it applied to page style.

So the question is: how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It should consider the font file(OPTIMA_0.woff) as a static file just like the css or js file you used.

If your static directory is like this:

```
|-index.html
|-css/
|----/main.css
|-fonts/
|-----/OPTIMA_0.woff
```

You can use the relative path in css file, assuming the file called main.css.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Optima';
    src: url('../fonts/OPTIMA_0.woff') format('woff');           
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: well...I cannot deal this comment formatting...
So, path is right in my scripts

Comment: So can you show me the uri for your css file? Maybe we can find out a solution based on it. BTW, which server application you use? How to config the static directory in it?

Comment: `@font-face{  
    font-family: 'Optima';
    src: url('fonts/OPTIMA_0.TTF') format('truetype'),    
        url('fonts/OPTIMA_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        /* url('fonts/OPTIMA_0.woff2') format('woff2'),  /*LOOKS THE ISSUE IS HERE */        
         url('fonts/OPTIMA_0.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
         url('fonts/OPTIMA_0.Optima') format('svg'),    
         url('fonts/OPTIMA_0.woff') format('woff'); 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my fault, wrong file name)